# Are there any ways to update the value of a cell based on if something is written in another cell in MUI X Datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

What i need is to change the value of a cell based on if something is written in another cell. If something is written in that cell which means cell both gains focus and something is being written inside it and finally loses focus, the value will change to 'a' in other cell. If nothing is written(which includes 2 conditions:user never clicks on the cell ever. which also means cell nevers gets focus and nothing is being written inside it. the second condition is user clicks on the cell, but makes cell lose focus with nothing being written inside it.) in this case the value will change to 'b'. How can this be done?

I have tried useState to do but couldn't find a way to figure it out.